# Which one is more preferrable and why

Tags: java

Which of the following code is better and why?  I have seen many programs written in the first way shown below. Why is it done so?

First Way:

```
 public static final int SIZE = 200000;
 public static int[] count;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    count = new int[SIZE];
 }
```

Second Way:

```
public static int[] count;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    count = new int[200000];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two benefits in extracting the constant into a static final field:

Firstly, it has a *name* - admittedly `SIZE` isn't a very good one (size of what? why?) but in other cases it can be very useful to make your intent clear. For example, it's obvious what this means:

```
private static final long SECONDS_PER_STANDARD_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60;
```

(although I'd usually use `TimeUnit` here). Having the same value within the code - or worse,
the actual numeric value instead of the expression - would be less clear. The above can be
broken down further, of course:

```
// TODO: Decide between long and int here. Using long means you don't need to be
// as careful when multiplying them together. (Think microseconds etc...)
private static final long HOURS_PER_STANDARD_DAY = 24;
private static final long MINUTES_PER_HOUR = 60;
private static final long SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60;
private static final long SECONDS_PER_HOUR = SECONDS_PER_MINUTE * SECONDS_PER_HOUR;
private static final long SECONDS_PER_STANDARD_DAY =
    HOURS_PER_STANDARD_DAY * SECONDS_PER_HOURS;
```

This is precisely the kind of thing I have in [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) - I have a public `NodaConstants`
class with a huge number of these constants, because they're useful both within Noda Time and
also in client code - and the meaning is immediately obvious from the name.

Additionally, it can be used in multiple places, which shows a relationship between those places. If the same number occurs three times in the source code, and you need to change one of them, do you need to change the other? It's hard to tell. If you use a constant, and if every place where the number is needed has carefully decided whether *semantically* they need the same value, then you can change the value of the constant and all the right places (and only the right places) will see that change.

Some developers take this to an extreme, banning all literals other than zero and one. Personally I view it as a more subtle decision than that. There's a cost to extracting the constant as well as a benefit - the value gets moved away from the code using it. If you're only using the value once, and it's clear from the context why you're using that value, then using the constant obscures the code rather than clarifying it.

I think it's always worth *considering* whether to extract a constant - but don't go either way in a knee-jerk way.

Answer (score 9):

`200000` is a [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).  We don't know what context it came from, what it's doing there, or what it means - if one had to change it to something else, it'd feel like an arbitrary change.  It could even break tests, business rule assumptions, or cost the company money.

Creating a constant that encapsulates its purpose gives the magic number meaning and context.  We now know that it relates specifically to SIZE, and if we were to change it, we would be increasing or decreasing the SIZE of an array.

To points made:  SIZE isn't the best name, and if you're only using it in one spot (i.e. in the array's initialization), a comment or some light documentation would shed as much light on why the array's size is set so arbitrarily high as the named constant.

Comment: I'd argue that a generically-named variable like `SIZE`, used only to instantiate the int array, tells you absolutely nothing extra. "What's `SIZE`? Oh, it's the size of the `int[]`" vs "what's `200000`? Oh, it's the size of the `int[]`". Declaring a variable doesn't tell you _why_ that's the size, or what tests or assumptions might be broken if you changed the value. If you use the value elsewhere and require/want them to be the same, then sure. But if it's just used once? Meh.

Comment: @yshavit It still brings something to the plate: the value of that constant is "outsourced" from the code block to an easily noticable place. Sure in this case it doesn't matter, but if code would be hundreds of lines, it would be harder to track down where it was if you wanted to change it.

Comment: why do people still declare constants even when they have to use them only once or twice

Comment: Clarity of intent.  You most certainly don't have to, but spare a thought for the poor guy who has to maintain your code later on.

Comment: @johny Why? ... exactly for the reason icza explains - it makes it easy to find the magic number instead of having to hunt it down in hundreds or thousands of lines of code. As a maintainer of a large financial application I have learned to worship them.